# Создать триггер отменяющий вставку по условию SQLite

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, триггер

Есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE "test" (
    "Field1"    INTEGER,
    "Field2"    INTEGER
);
```

Нужно что бы при вставке строк в таблицу, вставка отменялась, если значение в 1-ом поле меньше чем во 2-ом.

Например:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1,4); Вставка должна отмениться, поскольку 1-ое поле меньше 2-ого

INSERT INTO test VALUES(4,1); Здесь вставка должна пройти успешно
```

Насколько я понимаю, нужно сделать триггер BEFORE INSERT. А далее как?

Comment: Уточните, что делать, если одно или оба поля - NULL. И распространяется ли условие на обновление записи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нужно что бы при вставке строк в таблицу, вставка отменялась, если значение в 1-ом поле меньше чем во 2-ом.
>
> Насколько я понимаю, нужно сделать триггер BEFORE INSERT.

Совершенно не требуется.

```
CREATE TABLE "test" (
    "Field1" INTEGER,
    "Field2" INTEGER CHECK (Field1 >= Field2)
);
```

Условие будет проверяться и при вставке, и при изменении записи.

Если хотя бы одно из полей NULL, запись будет вставлена.